# Sony Xperia E can't install apps caused by storage problems

Tags: google-play-store, storage, sony-xperia

I've got a problen with my Sony Xperia E (Android 4.1.1.). 
In the settings it says there's still 1.37 Gb free storage but when trying to install an app (about 20mb) from google play I just get an error telling me there's not enought free storage left. I don't have root and I don't want to root my device.

I know this problem has been discussed several times on the internet and here in the forum but I couldn't find a working solution.

I'm hoping anyone can help.

Regards
Nils

Comment: Correction please, [android.se] is a strictly Q/A website and not a forum. Anyhow, did you see this 1.37Gb in the **Settings -> Storage** or **Settings -> Apps**? You can use an app like [Diskinfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo&hl=en)(<1MB) that can help you to tell the storage left for app installation (in `data`).

Comment: In Settings -> Storage but I think it should be the same. I'll try later to download Diskinfo.

Comment: No, it is not the same. There is a separate storage space reserved for apps installation which is different from the internal storage you use (music, pictures, etc). You can see apps storage space in Settings -> Apps, but Diskinfo would give you some other info as well (if you need).